# how to display percentage of column gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data files that I need to plot. Im setting xtic to the 1st column, which contains large number, i.e., 1000 000, 2000 000, .., 10 000 0000
using the command:

```
plot  "vec.dat" using 1:2:xtic(1) title 'line 1' with linespoints,
```

However, x-axis looks ugly, as such large numbers are being displayed in the x-axis. Im interested in showing only percentage of such values, how can this be done in gnuplot?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either scale all `x` value and add the scaling to the `x` label:

```
set termoption enhanced
set xlabel 'Values in 10^{6}'
plot "vec.dat" using ($1*1e-6):2 title 'line 1' with linespoints
```

or you can change the xtics format with

```
set termoption enhanced
set format x '%.1t 10^{%T}'
plot "vec.dat" using 1:2 title 'line 1' with linespoints
```

I would definitely prefer the first version. I don't see any reason for using `xtic` in your case.

Comment: I stop watching for a month or so and somehow you've managed to score 30 upvotes on the gnuplot tag in a month.  Kudos!  (I feel like I've never gotten that many ;-).  +1 for this one by the way.